# How to hide inherited dependencies in Versions Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, spring, maven, versions-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), together with `spring-boot`.

Problem: when running `versions:display-dependency-updates` to autoecheck for latest dependencies, I'm not only getting the updates defined in my `pom.xml`, but also all inherited dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Question: how can I prevent inheritance and just show the self-defined dependencies?

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
    <cxf.version>3.0.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

At best, the plugin would inform me of updates similar to:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent.....2.0.0 -> 2.0.3
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws..........3.0.0 -> 3.2.6
```

But instead, I'm getting output an all dependencies inherited from the spring parent.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `versions:display-property-updates` goal instead. This goal only considers the dependency versions that are given as properties, so it will not show the transitive dependencies. You'll have to add a few more version properties to your pom, but that's not a bad thing in general.

The documentation for the `versions:display-dependency-updates` goal does not include a flag to exclude transitive dependencies. So I assume it's not possible using that goal. I couldn't find any relevant open issues on [issues.apache.org](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) either, so it doesn't seem to be on the roadmap.

Comment: It seems that since versions-maven-plugin version 2.13.0 this solution is no longer valid as the parent pom is included in property resolution according to https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/commit/bce86461bdfd39ec066427c833649b5ff694426a So far I didn't find a setting to get back the previous behavior.

Comment: My comment above as been confirmed and default behavior will be back to pre-2.13.0 with the publication of version 2.14.0.